# Creating parallell timeline in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, schedule, timeline

I am trying to create a schedule in xcode, preferably Objective-C. Basically I will have some sessions over specific times that are going to be distributed over some locations/rooms and I want to have a parallell timeline for each of these rooms.

What I am looking for to create is something like the app Magine (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ1Y2.jpg).

I figure I will probably need to create a UICollectionViewLayout, but that is pretty much how far my knowledge goes. Any level of guides ot help is greatly appreciated. Maybe there is even an open source class somewhere that accomplishes just what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am looking for is obviously something like [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout). Hopefully I'll be able to modify the source code to better fit my needs.